# Why is the computed property being updated even though I didn't specify its dependencies?

Tags: ember.js

I have a schema structured something like this:

```
App = {};

App.Outer = Ember.Object.extend({
    inner: null,
    quantity: 0,

    count: function () {
        var self = this, inner = self.get('inner');
        return self.get('quantity') * inner.get('count');
    }.property('nothing')
});

App.Inner = Ember.Object.extend({
    count: 0
});
```

Yes, the 'count' computed property really is set to depend on a totally nonexistent property 'nothing'.  However it seems to get updated anyway:

```
var o1 = App.Outer.create({
    quantity: 2,
    inner: App.Inner.create({count: 4})
});

console.log(o1.get('count')); // => 8
o1.get('inner').set('count', 5);
console.log(o1.get('count')); // => 10
o1.set('inner', App.Inner.create({count: 10}));
console.log(o1.get('count')); // => 20
```

Am I missing something?  It knows what to update without me telling it what to depend on... can't be right, can it?  What am I misunderstanding about Ember computed properties?

Thanks

Comment: note that `.property('nothing')` is equivalent here to `.property()` --- that might simplify the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using `this.get('quantity')`, `inner.get('count')` you are telling it what it depends on. Every time you call `.get('count')` the function will go off and get the current values for those properties and therefore return the up to date result.

The `.property()` part comes into play when you bind the computed property count to something else e.g. a view. When you do that then making a change to quantity will automatically recalculate the count, and this new value will be propagated to whatever you have bound the count too.

You can see the difference in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/tomwhatmore/6gz8x/

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks.  If I want to test this behaviour from a unit test, how should I proceed?  I'm guessing make a temporary View object and bind to that property then check its bound property changes when the bound-to one changes...

Comment: @AsfandYarQazi I have to admit that I'm still working out the best way to test Ember projects, there's not much documentation on the topic around, so I've been trying some different things out over the last few days. This specific example though strikes me as not ideal for a unit test, you're basically just testing the framework, rather than your code. Ember already has plenty of tests for that. I think it would be covered better as part of an integration test.

Answer (score 3):

As of Ember 0.9.5, property values are not cached unless cacheable() is called on them. e.g.

```
...

count: function () {
    var self = this, inner = self.get('inner');
    return self.get('quantity') * inner.get('count');
}.property('nothing').cacheable()

...
```

For more background, see the discussion on this GitHub issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/38

Comment: Yeah, but in this case I was wondering why it was acting as if it was BEING cached :)

Comment: @AsfandYarQazi I've created a JSFiddle to try to better show how cacheable fits in: http://jsfiddle.net/pNC8t/

You can think of a property dependencies as "subscription". You're saying I want to know when this property changes. Bindings use this to know whether to update. The "cacheable" functionality uses this to know whether to execute the function again or just return the same result as the last time it ran.

Comment: @AsfandYarQazi Another take on explaining this clearly: When you use `.property('foo')`, you're saying make this function a property and notify me when `foo` changes. Bindings are another form of subscription. For bindings to update on a property change, you must have a subscription chain from the changing property to the binding. Lastly,`cacheable` lets you say don't reexecute the function again unless I've been notified something I depend on has changed.

Comment: Well, that seems like a more in depth version of the same answer as the previous one, but it's info that's welcome so up-vote :)